# ValueError: Invalid Literal error when passing integer value from form to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, python, jquery-mobile

I am trying to pass an `Integer` from a form to a `Javascript` function. I got the value alright using `parseInt()` like this:

```
var student_age= parseInt($("#age").val());
```

and then stored it as JSON like this

```
"age": student_age
```

but when i hit the submit button, i get an `Internal server error`. I traced it to my python code to the line where am trying to pass in the value from the form to the server.

```
student_age = int(self.request.get('age'))
```

This is where i am getting the `ValueError: Invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NaN'`

I have tried changing 
`"age": student_age` to `"age": str(student_age)` with no luck.

*Edit: Python Code:*

```
class StudentRegistrationHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
       ...
       if student:
           #do stuff
       else:
           student_age = int(self.request.get('age'))
           ...
```

Comment: _NaN_ is a valid literal in _JavaScript_, but not a valid literal in _Python_, you need some fallback behaviour for when the result of _parseInt_ produces _NaN_, e.g. an impossible value, `-1`

Comment: @PaulS. well it's true that `NaN` is a valid JavaScript literal, but it's not valid in JSON. JSON serialization from JavaScript turns `NaN` into `null`.

Comment: @Pointy it actually looks like it's becoming `"NaN"` from the message

Comment: @PaulS. yes I agree; what I meant was that we're not really talking about JSON if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks guys...but this only leaves me with more questions.

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` gives you the number or NaN if the string provided is not an number. NaN is short for Not-A-Number. Python raises an ValueError if `int` gets a string which is not a number.
You have two possibilities: Check in Javascript if the user enters a number and only send correct requests to the server or check in the python code, if the age-parameter is really a number. Best do both.

Comment: Isn't there a function to do this? That is, converting a string to an int before sending it to the server?

Comment: the function is called `parseInt`. But what should this function do if it doesn't get a number? Oh yes, it returns a special value `NaN` so that the programmer can check.

Comment: Lol.Yes.This is confusing.I have tried `radix` with no luck still.I'll keep trying.Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked, what's in `$("#age").val()`?

Comment: No i haven't.But in the form, i declared that the value returned is `number`

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: I just ran a test now, using 
`if (typeof student_age == "string") { alert('age is a string.') }`
 `if (typeof student_age=="number") { alert('age is a number.') }`
and it says it is a number.

Comment: NaN is a special value of a floating point number.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like you're trying to convert the *String* `"NaN"` to an *integer* using `int` (base 10) in *Python*. This won't work because *Python* does not recognize *NaN*.

In Python, it's okay to ask forgiveness

```py
try:
    student_age = int("NaN")
except:
    student_age = -1 # impossible age but valid int fallback
```

Now have

```
student_age == -1
```

and no exception raised

Comment: But the problem is, it is raising an exception where am trying to save the value for `student_age` for the first time. How am i going to use this?I am updating my question with my python code so you can see why i think this would be impossible(?)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what was wrong with my code.It was silly mistake on my part.I also had another variable declared as:

```
var year = parseInt($("year").val());
```

but i forgot to add the `#` before `year`. Since this variable was declared before the `student_age` variable, i thought the error affected both.I tested what was being stored in these variables using `console.log()` and saw that age had an int and year was NaN.